# => Operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

I have been searching thoroughly on Google but I can't seem to be able to find the answer. I am wondering what the `=>` operator means in the Ruby code shown below:

```ruby
def test_raising_a_particular_error
     result = nil
     begin
       # 'raise' and 'fail' are synonyms
       raise MySpecialError, "My Message"
    rescue MySpecialError => ex
       result = :exception_handled
     end

     assert_equal :exception_handled, result
     assert_equal "My Message", ex.message
end
```

Comment: Here it means *"if you catch some kind of `MySpecialError`, store it in a variable named `ex`"*.

Comment: @ndn, thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `=>` operator in Ruby. There are, however, two uses of `=>` in Ruby:

1. in a `Hash` literal between the key object and the value object
2. in a `rescue` clause after the exception filter expression, naming the variable the exception should be bound to

So, in this case, it's #2, and means "rescue any exception that is an instance of `MySpecialError` and bind it to the local variable named `ex`".

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. :) Is it true that it binds the `MySpecialError` to the local variable `ex` so that `ex` can be used later?